# ASP.NET C# DTO initialization by constructor with parameters or paramless constructor with curly braces in-line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, constructor, dto

Hi im just wondering how should I initialize my DTO objects in my ASPNET project, seems like everyone uses second approach but I dont know why and I can't really find clear answer. My argument for the first method with constructor with parameters is that when we add new field constructor also requires you to pass another paramter in all initialization places.

Frist Method

```
public class AuctionResponse
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public AuctionResponse(int price, string message)
    {
        Price = price
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

and then we use it like:

```
new AuctionResponse(price, message);
```

vs

Second Method

```
public class AuctionResponse
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and then we use it like:

```
new AuctionResponse() { Price: price, Message: message };
```

Answer (score 0):

The second approach might be more often used to avoid having to keep track of all the constructor parameters and the order that they should be passed in the event that you have a dto with a lot of properties.

Also in the event that the dto is updated, the constructor calls would also have to be updated with the new parameters vs just updating the one instance where the new property might be necessary/available.

```
new AuctionResponse(price, message, c, d, e, f , g...);
```

Also an auto mapper could be used if necessary.